# Advice on refactoring/scaling enormous events-based production table in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, optimization

I am hoping to get some advice regarding next steps to take for our production database that, in hindsight, has been very ill thought out.

We have an events based system that generates payment information based on "contracts" (a "contract" defines how/what the user gets paid).

Example schema:

```
Approx         Quantity is ess.        Quantity is slightly
5M rows        1-to-1 with "Events"    less, approx.
               i.e. ~5M rows           3M rows
----------     ----------------       --------------
| Events |     | Contract     |       | Payment    |
----------     ----------------       --------------
| id     |     | id           |       | id         |
| userId |  -> | eventId      | ----> | contractId |
| jobId  |     | <a bunch of  |       | amount     |
| date   |     | data to calc |       | currency   |
----------     | payments>    |       |------------|
               ----------------
```

There is some additional data on each table too such as generic "created_at", "updated_at", etc.

These are the questions I have currently come up with (please let me know if I'm barking up the wrong tree):

**Should I denormalise the payment information?**

Currently, in order to get a payment based on an event ID we need to do minimum one join but realistically we have to do two (there are rarely scenarios where we want a payment based only on some contract information). With 5M rows (and growing on a daily basis) it takes well over 20s to do a normal select with sort, let alone a join. My thought is that by moving the payment info directly onto the events table we can skip the joins in order to get payment information.

**Should I be "archiving" old rows from Events table?**

Since the Events table has so many new rows constantly (and also needs to be read from for other business logic purposes) should I be implementing some strategy to move events where payments have already been calculated into some "archive" table? My thought is that this will keep the very I/O-heavy Events table more "freed up" in order to be read/written to faster.

**What other optimisation strategies should I be thinking about?**

The application in question is currently live to paying customers and our team is growing concerned about the manpower that will be required to keep this unoptimised setup in-check. Are there any "quick wins" that we could perform on the tables/database in order to speed things up? (I've read about "indexing" but I haven't grasped the purpose well enough to be confident to deploy it to a production database)

Thank you so much in advance for any advice you can give!

**Edit to include DB information:**

`explain (analyze, buffers) select * from "event" order by "updatedAt" desc`

```
Gather Merge  (cost=1237571.93..1699646.19 rows=3960360 width=381) (actual time=71565.082..76242.131 rows=5616130 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  Buffers: shared hit=107649 read=211715, temp read=805207 written=805973
  I/O Timings: read=76365.059
  ->  Sort  (cost=1236571.90..1241522.35 rows=1980180 width=381) (actual time=69698.164..70866.085 rows=1872043 loops=3)
        Sort Key: "updatedAt" DESC
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 725448kB
        Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 685968kB
        Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 714432kB
        Buffers: shared hit=107649 read=211715, temp read=805207 written=805973
        I/O Timings: read=76365.059
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..339111.80 rows=1980180 width=381) (actual time=0.209..26506.333 rows=1872043 loops=3)
              Buffers: shared hit=107595 read=211715
              I/O Timings: read=76365.059
Planning Time: 1.167 ms
Execution Time: 76799.910 ms
```

Comment: 5 million rows is hardly "enourmous"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name According to the speed of our system it is!  That's why I'm here for advice about the optimisation

Comment: "*With 5M rows (and growing on a daily basis) it takes well over 20s to do a normal select with sort, let alone a join*" a simple select or join on two small tables like that shouldn't take that long. I guess your queries aren't optimized or you are missing indexes to properly support the type of query you are using

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would you be able to expand on your point about indexing? You seem confident in saying it shouldn't be taking that long so now I'm hopeful for potentially a "quick win" with some indexing?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name _queries aren't optimized_ - I'm talking literally just "SELECT * FROM Events ORDER BY createdAt" is taking well over 20s. I guess something is really wrong 

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your advice. I have updated the question with the explain query now. As far as indexes I don't believe there are any, but I'm failing to understand how I should be adding them? I've read about "having to maintain" indexes and worried about the attention that would require?

Comment: Why are you constantly reading all rows from the table? That sounds like a strange approach. Anyway: your table seems much wider than what you wrote: the average row length is 381 bytes, so you are retrieving (and sorting) roughly 700MB each time. But your number of blocks seems way to high for only 2 million rows - does `vacuum full analyze events;` change anything? You could get rid of the sort stop by creating an index on `created_at`

Comment: Thanks for your time and insight on this. We're not specifically reading all of the rows all the time, but I am constantly checking the latest for various business logic debugging purposes with a "LIMIT 200" query - but I assume that query is still limited by the fact it has to sort the data too? If I'm sorting by "created_at" with this limit query would it be beneficial to create an index there?

Comment: Yes, the index would be helpful - especially in combination with a LIMIT

Comment: Does the user ever make partial payments on a contract, or pay on multiple contracts with one payment?  Both of those are pretty common scenarios.

Comment: If events and contracts are 1:1, why are they different tables to start with?

Comment: Refactoring things already in production is hard.  Tuning queries is generally much easier to do (or attempt, anyway), but you need to tune the queries that will actually get run in production.

Comment: Can you give Postgres more memory (work_mem)? If I read the explain properly properly it seems your sort is taking 99% of the time. Doing a disk sort "*Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 725448kB*", and that is the slowest possible process. Try adding 1G or 2G.